# which time period covers date string over datetime column

Tags: mysql, datetime

My question is a restlessness I been having for a time. So, here it goes:

If I have a datetime column and perform a date search without the time 'yyyy-mm-dd' in a between statement. Which period of time does the query covers?. From this, I can figure some others like timezone related or daylights changes.

So, have you any knowledge or source to check this information?

I know this is not the kind of filter to apply in a datetime column but due a human mistake in a query once I still have doubts

Thank you

Comment: Please look I'm not asking how to filter a datetime query. My question is more on the deep understanding of how does MySQL handle a datetime filter when it doesn't have all the data at hand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) exact alternative to `DATE(ColumnName) = DATE'yyyy-mm-dd'` is

```
ColumnName >= TIMESTAMP'yyyy-mm-dd' AND
ColumnName < TIMESTAMP'yyyy-mm-dd' + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

Something like

```
ColumnName >= 'yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00' AND
ColumnName <= 'yyyy-mm-dd 23:59:59'
```

is not only more complicated (and bug prone), but also leaves out any values between `'yyyy-mm-dd 23:59:59.000001'` and `'yyyy-mm-dd 23:59:59.999999'`.

Comment: =+3 for this answer. Necessary read: [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) Although the blog post is about SQL Server, the same concepts apply to MySQL. "Don't use `BETWEEN` but inclusive-exclusive range conditions", as in @Ziggy's answer.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you @ypercubeᵀᴹ and Ziggy for your comments. ypercube's post is a MUST READ. Also consider take a look at [mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Answer (score 0):

Looking for date only with `DATETIME` column, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE DATE(ColumnName) = '2003-12-31'
```

The query above will gives you data with dates of `2003-12-31` excluding the information about the time. As long as you've formatted the `DATETIME` column into date for 'date only' fetching, time will be ignored.

For using timezone in query, time will be needed with at least of '00:00:00'. I dunno if mysql will give your 'date only' automatic or default time when timezoning, I haven't tested that.

> For DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types, [HERE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)
>
> For Date and Time Functions, [HERE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Thank you @rhavendc. Please look my answer to RolandoMySQLDBA. By the way this approach is not efficient as it does not work properly with indexes

Comment: @AlwinKesler It's just an example. I didn't recommend anything xD

Answer (score 0):

For purposes of comparing `DATEs`, `DATETIMEs`, and/or `TIMESTAMPs`, `'2017-09-14'`, `'2017-09-14 00:00:00'`, and `'2017-09-14 00:00:00.000000'` are identical.

As for timezone stuff, that is not readily available.

Meanwhile, I wholeheartedly agree with Ziggy's pattern:

```
ColumnName >= 'yyyy-mm-dd' AND
ColumnName  < 'yyyy-mm-dd' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

(but without the casting).

This takes care of end-of-month, leap-days, etc., *and* avoids the common mistake of including two midnights in one day.  It also works identically regardless of whether `ColumName` declared `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or `DATETIME(6)`; that is, *no* change to `yyyy-mm-dd` (assuming you want the boundary to be at midnight).